# Android Paypal user login using sdk

Tags: android, paypal, braintree, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-android-sdk

Unable to find login or user registration part in SDK documents.

**Want to Payout user after login or sign up paypal account(This payout could be rewards or cashback)**

Was able to find article https://www.sitepoint.com/implement-user-log-paypal/

**Also paypal android sdk is deprecated** https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK not sure if they have sdk for android unable to find.

How can I exactly implement user paypal login in my app ?

This what I want to do

1. user comes to app
2. Login or signup paypal account
3. After successful login or signup will payout user using account details(This payout could be rewards or cashback)

**how to implement paypal login or user auth in android app and get access toked?**

Update:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK on this link it is written paypal sdk is depricated use BrainTree direct, is payout possible using Braintree direct?

Answer (score 0):

For a user to log in and connect their account to your app/service, use [Log in with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/).

Once you have their information, to send them money in a programatic way you can see about [getting access to Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts), which can be used from an API call from a server. Actions in the app could trigger that server's API call.

Comment: want to check user is logged in or not

Comment: You have to implement your own log in functionality to be able to check whether they are logged in or not.

Comment: sdk does not provide this?

Comment: Log in with PayPal uses a JavaScript button.

Comment: oh how to do it in the native app?

Comment: how to paypal login or user auth in android app and get access toked?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If you want to have the user log in to PayPal before doing anything, implement the Log in with PayPal service. Other then that, be more clear about your question and requirements.

Comment: I want to implement user login in app using android sdk thats it nothing else rest I will figure out. Question is pretty clear .

Comment: Well, from that description you want Log in with PayPal.  There is a server-side portion to this integration, for doing the REST API calls.

Comment: I don't want to do that. Is there anything as simple as facebook login in app?

Comment: If you don't want to implement Log in with PayPal, there is no solution for users to log in with PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Use latest PayPal Android Native SDK. It's super easier now and easy to use

Link:
https://github.com/paypal/android-checkout-sdk